# Windows keyboard shortcut to access the context menu of a pinned icon

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

For example Win+1 will launch (or switch to) the first pinned application on the taskbar. Is there a similar keyboard shortcut to open the context menu of a pinned icon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[number key]</kbd> does this.

Answer (score 0):

Windows + T until you focus on the icon, then use menu key or shift + F10 to access context menu

When in an application like Excel, to access the context menu of a tab by keyboard;

First, press F6 to activate the sheet tabs. Next, use the left or right arrow keys to select the sheet you want, then you can use Ctrl + Space to select that sheet. Repeat the arrow and Ctrl + Space steps to select additional sheets. Right-click a sheet tab, and then click the Select All Sheets option.

[see link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/select-worksheets-096b40c9-0ee7-4980-bac6-cc92aec7b266#:%7E:text=want%20to%20select.-,By%20keyboard%3A%20First%2C%20press%20F6%20to%20activate%20the%20sheet%20tabs,steps%20to%20select%20additional%20sheets.&text=Right%2Dclick%20a%20sheet%20tab,the%20Select%20All%20Sheets%20option.)

In the context of a browser, you move focus by Tab, then right click.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1177670)